# jsonb_strip_nulls equivalent in SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server, null

I'm using this request to get JSON from some a column in POSTGRES:

```
SELECT 
    jsonb_strip_nulls(json_build_object(
        'employee', c."info"->'employee2', 'product', c."info"->'product2'
    )::jsonb) as info
FROM
    item."Item" AS c
WHERE 
    "rootId" = '40a8cb67-84f8-33b5-87dc-e1b039858d43' 
GROUP BY 
    "id") ...;
```

`jsonb_strip_nulls` omits unnecessary fields with null values. And I need to do the same in SQL Server.

I'm using this request to retrieve the items:

```
SELECT 
    '{ "employee": ' + JSON_QUERY(info, '$.employee') + ', "product": ' + JSON_QUERY(info, '$.product2') + ' }' AS info
FROM  
    item.[Item] AS c 
WHERE 
    "rootId" = '3B319A76-A2C7-3DA1-8ECE-4736E4749261' 
GROUP BY 
    "id") ...;
```

When I try to get some not existing fields, I get nulls for all. But I need to omit fields that are not present in JSON.

For example, if the `product2` field doesn't exist and 'employee' exists I want to see employees in the response. How I can do It?

UPD: SQL Server version:

```
Microsoft Azure SQL Edge Developer (RTM) - 15.0.2000.1552 (ARM64)
```

Info contents is json type field, something like:

```
{
  "_key": {
    "id": "3b8d1ed7-c3ec-32ec-a083-2ddc17152e94",
    "rootId": "15c85327-9628-3685-b84a-375b546ba92a",
  },
  "employee": {
    "idNumber": "3",
    "gender": "M",
    ....
  },
  "product": {
    "plan": "prod",
    "class": "1",
    "_type": "Product",
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual content of the `info` column and what is your SQL Server version?

Comment: see update in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to build the expected JSON content with `FOR JSON PATH` and `WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER` modifier:

```
SELECT info = (
  SELECT 
     employee = JSON_QUERY(info, '$.employee'), 
     product = JSON_QUERY(info, '$.product2')
  FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
)  
FROM item
```

On an Azure instance you may use `JSON_OBJECT()` (... I'm not sure if this feature is supported on Microsoft Azure SQL Edge Developer):

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
   'employee': JSON_QUERY(info, '$.employee'),
   'product': JSON_QUERY(info, '$.product2')
   ABSENT ON NULL
) AS info
FROM Item
```

Comment: Might as well use `OPENJSON` if you have multiple fields.

Comment: @Charlieface, yes, you are right. It's just a simplified example, the actual scenario is probably more complex.

Comment: Looks like `JSON_OBJECT()` is "not supported" on Edge https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql-edge/features#unsupported-features

Comment: The first solution works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can parse out the JSON and rebuild it using `FOR JSON PATH` inside a subquery. `FOR JSON` by default does not give null values.

```sql
SELECT
  (
    SELECT
      j.*
    FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
  ) AS info
FROM item.Item AS c 
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(c.info)
  WITH (
    employee nvarchar(max) AS JSON,
    product2 nvarchar(max) AS JSON
  ) j
WHERE rootId = '3B319A76-A2C7-3DA1-8ECE-4736E4749261';
```